# Do not begin a sentence with an abbreviation

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I am using the `glossaries` package. How can I make sure that a sentence does not start with an abbreviation?

Comment: You are the author, you define your sentences. Don't put the abbreviation at the beginning of a sentence. ;-) Seriously, i think there is a macro that will always print the long form. Maybe `glsL` or something, would need to look it up on the manual. EDIT: `glsentrylong`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the \acrlong command if you want the long (full) text of anacronym, you defined.

Here's a howto page for the glossaries package: [sharelatex.com](https://de.sharelatex.com/learn/Glossaries)